# Data transfer at certain frequencies

Tags: information-theory

I am curious as to what the maximum data transmission rates are to a given frequency.

Say you have a com channel with a frequency of 10 khz. How many bits/s would you be able to send?

Thanks!

Comment: This is very much dependant on other parameters, e.g. how accurate can you reconstruct the amplitude and phase of the signal. This is primarily dependant on the a) capability of the hardware used and b) how noisy the transmission channel is (and the dampening). Theoretically, you could transmit an arbitrary amount of data (disregarding quantum-mechanical effects)

Answer (score 3):

Channel Capacity or maximum data rate is the maximum rate at which data can be transmitted over a given communication link, or channel.

In general, information is conveyed by change in values of the signal in time. So more the frequency of a signal, more is the achievable data rate.

For a communication channel,

Δf⋅Δt≈1

To transmit one signal, a pulse of length Δt (in time) is required. If one signal represents one bit, then the data rate is about 1/Δt. So the maximum data rate in bit/second is about the same as the band width Δf in Hertz.

But this is an incredible underestimate of the information capacity of a transmission system. It assumes that you are sending rectangular shaped pulses.
Using different encoding schemes, more than one bit can be represented by one cycle of signal.

The channel capacity of a channel increases proportionally with the bandwidth. But in practice, we cannot keep increasing the signal bandwidth infinitely. Apart from this, there are other standard transmission constraints in the form of different channel noise sources that strictly limit the signal bandwidth to be used. According to Shannon Hartley equation, the only limit to data rate in a given bandwidth is, the Signal to Noise Ratio.

Using Shannon formula we can obtain an absolute limit of the maximum data transmission rate.

$C = B + log_2(1 + S/N)$

C - Channel capacity
B - Bandwidth
S - Average received signal power over the bandwidth
N - Average noise over the bandwidth

Comment: What would the S and N units be? And I assume for bandwidth you'd use bits/s right? @Smrithi.Prabhu

Comment: Bandwidth is the difference between upper and lower frequencies of the channel. So it is measured in hertz. S and N are measurer in watts